# How to update lists after delete a category

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, use-effect, use-state

I want to update the Category list after delete a category, I used custom hook for fetching data from the server. I'm not sure how to update state on custom fetch hook

```js
const {data, error, loading} = useFetch("/api/admin/category");
    const [category, setCategory]= useState([]);

    useEffect(() => {
        setCategory(data)
    },[])

    const deleteHandler = (id) => {

        const deleteRequest = async () => {
            const data = await axios.delete(`/api/admin/category/${id}`);
            return data;
        }

        deleteRequest()
            .then(res => {
                data.filter((item) => {
                    return id !== item.id;
                })
            })
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding `data` as the dependency to the `useEffect` hook may help, try this,

```
    const {data, error, loading} = useFetch("/api/admin/category");
    const [category, setCategory]= useState([]);

    useEffect(() => {
        setCategory(data)
    },[data])

    const deleteHandler = (id) => {

        const deleteRequest = async () => {
            const data = await axios.delete(`/api/admin/category/${id}`);
            return data;
        }

        deleteRequest()
            .then(res => {
                data.filter((item) => {
                    return id !== item.id;
                })
            })
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

in your custom hook add `data` to your dependency array;

in your component instead of the folowing

```
useEffect(() => {
  setCategory(data)
},[])
```

try to use the spread operator

```
useEffect(() => {
  setCategory([...data])
},[data])
```